# Java limit KeyListener update

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

So, I have a KeyListener added to my JFrame, and a Thread to my JPanel which is added to my JFrame.  The problem is that the thread repaints slower than the notification of keylistener...is there a way I can limit the keylistener to 4 keys per second(Or whatever).

Comment: The `KeyListener` is depended on the OS, so my first thought is no, probably not...

Comment: Could you clarify the *the thread repaints less then the updating of keylistener* part. Not every time you call `repaint` will actually trigger a `repaint`. It will only schedule one, but Swing might decide to group multiple repaint calls together. If you want to do animation, check the links on the [Swing tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: The thread repaints then sleeps 250ms, but I wonder if I could sync the keylistener with this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `Timer` in the `KeyListener`, or simply keep track of the last time a key was pressed and compare that with the current time.

This allows you to quit early from the `KeyListener` before any of your logic is reached. You can however not stop the `KeyListener` from being triggered, except when you constantly remove it and add it again after 250 ms.

Also note that in Swing you typically would use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of a `KeyListener`, although they would have the exact same problem.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually working on one, but was hoping java actually had something for this. Seems to be working ok and no lag.

Comment: `is there a way I can limit the keylistener to 4 keys per second(Or whatever).` this is exactly job for Swing Action (a few methods how to stop, start or pause), with Swing Timer